# Subtract or add to random number generator

Tags: c, random

I'm having this issue where the rand num generated doesn't increase the way I'd like it to. I've tried multiple ways to increase the value if the user enters -1 or decrease the value is the user enters 1. If user enters -1 the projected output, x, should increase between the first output and the upper bound values and if the user enters 1 it should find one between the first output and the lower bound values. A portion of my code is below. Any help is appreciated.

I've tried with no luck:

```
i = x (rand() % (upper + lower));
x = i +1;
```

Portion of code:

```
switch(input)
{
case -1:
{
x = x+1+ (rand() % (upper-x-1));
printf("My guess is %d \n", x);
break;
}

case 0:
{
printf("I win\n");
break;
}

case 1:
{
x = (rand() % (upper+lower)) +lower;
printf("My guess is %d \n", x);
break;
}
default: printf("Wrong choice try again\n");
break;
```

EDIT: Changed the -1 case but it adds 4 then increments by 1 and stops at 55 which is correct but I cannot figure out the skipping of 4. I'm trying another way which is if the user enters lower = 1 and upper = 55 if the first number generated is 35 then it would search between 36-54 within that range, but a random number like 42 not just incrementing by one.

Comment: What does "first output" mean?

Comment: So you want to generate random numbers between in an interval of `[hi,lo]`?

Comment: The first output guesses a number higher than the one originally guessed. Yes, between high and low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it seems to me is that you are trying to generate the random number the wrong way. To make a lower and upper bound like you are describing, try this instead:

```
x = lower + (rand() % (upper-lower)); // lower <= x < upper
```

In the case of -1, you can try using `x+1` for the lower bound. In the case of decreasing the number, make the upper bound equal to `x`.

```
case -1:
{
  if (x < upper-1) {
    x = x+1 + (rand() % (upper-x-1));
  }
...

case 1:
{
  if (x > lower) {
    x = lower + (rand() % (x-lower));
  }
...
```

I'm not sure what values you have defined in the `upper` and `lower` variables, but only make sure that the lower limit is smaller than the upper limit. I have also added a special condition where a division by zero could occur.

Comment: The upper and lower values are inputted by the user.

Comment: In that case, making sure that `lower < upper` before that procedure starts will be enough. I advise you to re-read my answer, I just added something that will prevent the code from dividing by 0.

Comment: The only problem that I see in that code is that it doesn't add 1 when it loops to do another guess. If i do lower = 1 upper = 55, it starts at 48 then jumps to 52, 53, 54.

Comment: Don't use modulus with rand(), you will get biased results. Using floating points is better, or iterate until in bounds.

Comment: Without mod I get values outside the upper and lower bounds. With mod it does not go out of those bounds.

Comment: @Oblivion24 That is why you divide by `( double )RAND_MAX`.

Comment: @Oblivion24 Let's say the current `x` is 12. If -1 is entered, the next x will be `13 +rand()%(upper-13)`, which makes a number between 13 and the upper boundary. In the case of 1, the next x will be `lower+(rand()%(12-lower)))`, which is just a number between the lower boundary and no larger than 11. If this is not the result you intended, please clarify.

Comment: @self I understand the issue, but I simply opted to solve the original matter before even thinking about changing this naive approach of generating the numbers. I'm more of a C++ person, and I'd use the appropriate random number distribution data types for the intended goal.

Comment: @E_net4 I believe I'm confusing myself as well. When you say if I enter -1 the next x will be 13+rand()%(upper-13), which what I'm trying to do is either print the next value as 13 OR have it print a value above 12 and lower than the upper value. Either way would work.

Comment: @Oblivion24 Then I believe you have what you want. But if you want the upper bound to be included in the accepted range (so that the guessed number can be 55 on that previous example), you must either consider that in the generated numbers (by adding 1 to all divisors) or previously increment the upper bound: `upper++;`

Comment: @E_net4 I continue to tweak it, it's still not giving me what values I need but you got me on the right track. Thanks!

Comment: @Oblivion24 that is strange. You should edit your question to include the latest changes and problems you have encountered.